# p2p protocol on top of TLS, synchronizing intermediate certificates

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Imagine a bitcoin-like network where peers communicate using a custom protocol on top of TLS. When connection between two peers is being established each party verifies each other's certificate.
Root certificate is shipped with the software.

There might be intermediate certificates which will be created after software is shipped. The question is what is the best approach for delivering new intermediate certificates when they are created and how to implement certificate revocation?

For example there are 2 peers `p1` and `p2` with certificates `c1` and `c2`, each of them is signed by an intermediate certificates `i1` and `i2`, which are signed by the root certificate.

Right now I can imagine it can be implemented using a centralized server which provides a list of all intermediate certificates issued and peers just pull this data from time to time to keep their local copy up to date.

Is there a common way on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any need to invent a new technology here to somehow distribute this information. Just use what is already there for this purpose:

- Intermediate certificates are usually send within the TLS handshake together with the leaf certificate. There is no need to distribute these up-front.
- Revocation of certificates can be done with established technologies like OCSP, either by asking a central server (OCSP responder) if the certificate is revoked or (preferable)  by sending the necessary OCSP responses already during the TLS handshake (OCSP stapling).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: What is the general approach for installing a certificate in a way that it's only accessible\used by my application? For example what would the process look like when intermediate certificate is issued and then it issues a certificate for the end user. Should end user install intermediate certificate manually?

Comment: @NoEscape: each peer which has its own certificate must also serve (and therefore have) the necessary intermediate certificates . These should get bundled and installed together with the leaf certificate (however this is done in your specific case).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers, that really helped me to identify what I should read about.